# Logon script on windows server 2008 fails to run

Tags: windows-server-2008, logon-scripts

I'm setting up two servers with windows server 2008, one running file, printer and application services, with the other one running Norman Endpoint Security. I've set up a logon script that in turn runs a kixtart script which sets up a network share and a network printer. The script itself works fine, but it won't run on logon. I've tried to make it work both through user profile settings in ADDS and through GPO, but neither works. I've browsed the microsoft support forums, but have yet to find a working solution. The script did run on logon two days ago through ADDS user profile, and the settings haven't been changed since then.

Edit: I did some testing, and GPO itself works - I can set settings for IE, the desktop and such, but the logon script still won't execute through neither GPO or ADDS.

Comment: so you can run the script via \\fqdn\netlogon\scriptname.xxx correct

Comment: Yeah, I can run the script manually and it does what it's supposed to, but it won't run on logon.